# I am not able to get direct messages with Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, dm

I've used Tweepy for a year, but now I face a problem that I´m not able to fix.

I want to get direct messages sent:

`api.list_direct_messages(100)`

but I have this error message:

`TypeError: list_direct_messages() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Any idea? Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. What version of Tweepy and Python are you using? Can you provide the full traceback? What happens when you specify it as the `count` kwarg?

Comment: It was my fault. Now I´m using the latest tweepy version and it´s working correctly

Answer (score 0):

[This was resolved by updating to the latest version of Tweepy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59494088/i-am-not-able-to-get-direct-messages-with-tweepy#comment105185199_59494088):

> It was my fault. Now I´m using the latest tweepy version and it´s working correctly